# Applying on item click listener on item in the listview

Tags: android, sqlite, android-cursoradapter

This is my code of database helper class can anyone please tell me what am i doing wrong that email column is not being added in the table and each time I am getting error that table has no cloumn name person_email

package com.example.and;

```
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class AndroidOpenDbHelper {

    private static final String TAG = AndroidOpenDbHelper.class.getSimpleName();

    // database configuration
    // if you want the onUpgrade to run then change the database_version
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "mydatabase.db";

    // table configuration
    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "person_table";         // Table name
    private static final String PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_ID = "_id";     // a column named "_id" is required for cursor
    private static final String PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_NAME = "person_name";
    private static final String PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_NUMBER = "person_contact_number";
    private static final String PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_EMAIL = "person_email";

    private DatabaseOpenHelper openHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase database;

    // this is a wrapper class. that means, from outside world, anyone will communicate with PersonDatabaseHelper,
    // but under the hood actually DatabaseOpenHelper class will perform database CRUD operations 
    public AndroidOpenDbHelper(Context aContext) {

        openHelper = new DatabaseOpenHelper(aContext);
        database = openHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    public void insertData (String aPersonName, String aPersonContactNumber, String aPersonEmail) {

        // we are using ContentValues to avoid sql format errors

        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

        contentValues.put(PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_NAME, aPersonName);
        contentValues.put(PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_NUMBER, aPersonContactNumber);
        contentValues.put(PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_EMAIL, aPersonEmail);


        database.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
    }

    public Cursor getAllData () {

        String buildSQL = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME;

        Log.d(TAG, "getAllData SQL: " + buildSQL);

        return database.rawQuery(buildSQL, null);
    }

    // this DatabaseOpenHelper class will actually be used to perform database related operation 

    private class DatabaseOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        public DatabaseOpenHelper(Context aContext) {
            super(aContext, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
            // Create your tables here

            String buildSQL = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "( " + PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                    PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_NAME + " TEXT, " + PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_NUMBER + " TEXT " +")" ; 
                    //+ PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_EMAIL + "TEXT )";

            Log.d(TAG, "onCreate SQL: " + buildSQL);

            sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(buildSQL);
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            // Database schema upgrade code goes here

            String buildSQL = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME;

            Log.d(TAG, "onUpgrade SQL: " + buildSQL);

            sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(buildSQL);       // drop previous table

            onCreate(sqLiteDatabase);               // create the table from the beginning
        }
    }
}
```

This is my MainActivity class

```
package com.example.and;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ClipData.Item;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private DataCursorAdapter customAdapter;
    private AndroidOpenDbHelper databaseHelper;
    private static final int ENTER_DATA_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
    private ListView listView;

    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        databaseHelper = new AndroidOpenDbHelper(this);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_data);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AddNewUndergraduateActivity.class);
              //  intent.putExtra("number",itemclicked );
                startActivity(intent);
                //Log.d(TAG, "clicked on item: " + position);
            }
        });

        // Database query can be a time consuming task ..
        // so its safe to call database query in another thread
        // Handler, will handle this stuff for you <img src="http://s0.wp.com/wp-includes/images/smilies/icon_smile.gif?m=1129645325g" alt=":)" class="wp-smiley">

        new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                customAdapter = new DataCursorAdapter(MainActivity.this, databaseHelper.getAllData());
                listView.setAdapter(customAdapter);
            }
        });
    }

    public void onClickEnterData(View btnAdd) {

        startActivityForResult(new Intent(this, AddNewUndergraduateActivity.class), ENTER_DATA_REQUEST_CODE);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == ENTER_DATA_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            databaseHelper.insertData(data.getExtras().getString("tag_person_name"), data.getExtras().getString("tag_person_contact_number"), 
                    data.getExtras().getString("tag_person_email")
                    );


            customAdapter.changeCursor(databaseHelper.getAllData());
        }
    }
```

}

Now I want to know how to pass the item selected to the other activity and fetch data from data according to the selected item. since my list item is a customized cursor object.So, I cant recognize how to do it.

this is my cursor adapter

```
package com.example.and;



import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.CursorAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class DataCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

    public DataCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor c) {
        super(context, c);
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        // when the view will be created for first time,
        // we need to tell the adapters, how each item will look
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View retView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listcell, parent, false);

        return retView;
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        // here we are setting our data
        // that means, take the data from the cursor and put it in views

        TextView textViewPersonName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_person_name);
        textViewPersonName.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(cursor.getColumnName(1))));

        TextView textViewPersonPIN = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_person_pin);
        textViewPersonPIN.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(cursor.getColumnName(2))));

        TextView textViewPersonEMAIL = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_person_email);
        textViewPersonPIN.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(cursor.getColumnName(3))));
    }
```

}

Comment: I think because you have commented this line `//+ PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_EMAIL + "TEXT )";`

Comment: Why you comment out  `//+ PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_EMAIL + "TEXT )";`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove comment and correct your query with below:

```
String buildSQL = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "(" + PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_NAME + " TEXT, " + PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_NUMBER + " TEXT,"  
                + PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_EMAIL + " TEXT)";
```

And reinstalled your app.

Answer (score 7):

You've commented out the code that creates that column:

```
//+ PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_EMAIL + "TEXT )";
```

You also need a space between column name and its type `TEXT`, like

```
+ PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_EMAIL + " TEXT )";
```

After editing the SQLite helper `onCreate()`, uninstall your app so the `onCreate()` gets run again. See [When is SQLiteOpenHelper onCreate() / onUpgrade() run?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21881992/when-is-sqliteopenhelper-oncreate-onupgrade-run) for more.